# Is it possible to determine how many lines of code are being checked into a build?

Tags: svn, line

Is it possible to determine how many lines of code are being checked into a build?

For example, how many lines of code went into main-dev build #50

I use SVN and Hudson server.

Please let me know your input.

Thanks

Comment: If you start measuring LOC changes per commit, please reward your developers whose change is negative.

Answer (score 0):

Try StatSVN:   http://www.statsvn.org/index.html

Here's an example report (for Java):  http://www.statsvn.org/jdepend-report.html

Comment: What part do you need help with?

Comment: Well,How to implement StatSVN, right now I used cloc tool which reported over all code lines in that branch but I want a diff between each build.Its taking long time during build if I use cloc it might take long time during run time.

Comment: The instructions are on the Wiki page, here:  http://wiki.statsvn.org/ in the section "Quick Start".  Have you tried those steps?  If so, what's not working?

Answer (score 0):

I use the following script (bash shell in linux) to compute the current lines of code being modified locally compared to the most resent version:

```
insert=`svn diff -x -b | grep "^+" | grep -v -c "^+++"`
delete=`svn diff -x -b | grep "^-" | grep -v -c "^---"`
loc=`expr $insert + $delete`
echo "$loc lines diff (Inserted $insert, deleted $delete)."
```

This gives you the output like this:

```
106 lines diff (Inserted 65, deleted 41).
```

To check the lines of codes changes of a past version, you can simply use the `-r` argument.  The following script takes one argument as the version of interest:

```
ver=$1
nextVer=`expr $ver + 1`
insert=`svn diff -r$ver:$nextVer -x -b | grep "^+" | grep -v -c "^+++"`
delete=`svn diff -r$ver:$nextVer -x -b | grep "^-" | grep -v -c "^---"`
loc=`expr $insert + $delete`
echo "$loc lines diff (Inserted $insert, deleted $delete)."
```